# What is Wasabi?

Tags: programming-languages

On [Joel Spolsky's blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/), I often read something about "Wasabi" and if I check Wikipedia, it mentions that [it's an in-house programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FogBugz#Wasabi).

What is it? Why do they use it? And why isn't it public?

Comment: hot spicey green paste which is yummy with Sushi

Comment: Podcast on the subject: http://www.hanselminutes.com/493/killing-off-wasabi-a-20yr-old-vbscript-problem-solved-with-2015-roslyn-tech "Scott talks to Jacob Krall from Fog Creek Software about how his team used the open source C# Roslyn compiler to bring their ancient VBScript-style language called "Wasabi" into the 21st century. "

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Also mentioned at: http://movingfulcrum.com/why-fogbugz-lost-to-jira/ which lists it as one of the top reasons why Fogbugz lost to JIRA. Now dead http://blog.fogcreek.com/killing-off-wasabi-part-1/. Targeted .NET.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would start with [The Origin of Wasabi](https://web.archive.org/web/20111124130043/http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-origin-of-wasabi/):

> As the primary developer and
>   maintainer of Wasabi, I've wanted to
>   write a series of articles on Wasabi
>   for awhile, and last week, I decided
>   to talk to Joel about it. Today, I
>   will start off with a short history of
>   the language, and later, I will talk
>   about some of its cooler features and
>   where we want to take it in the
>   future.

Comment: Great. I ended up finding 5 articles on that blog about Wasabi  http://citydesknews.com/blog/category/Wasabi.aspx

Comment: The link above in the accepted answer is broken, but an updated link can be found [here](http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-origin-of-wasabi/)

Comment: All the links are dead now ):

Answer (score 5):

Here's a recent update from 2013:

> In the beginning, there was Thistle. Thistle was, at best, a glorified
>   regex that converted ASP to PHP. It was written by an intern, and it
>   showed.
>
> Later, Thistle was broadened out into an ASP to PHP compiler. Compiler
>   was still a loose term; there was still a lot of regex magic that
>   relied on you following Hungarian apps notation. That said, I'm fairly
>   confident that this version of Thistle did build an AST for code
>   generation, which does mean it qualified as a real compiler.
>
> That matters because this version of Thistle was extended out with two
>   additional features: it could compile VBScript to JavaScript, and it
>   added some conveniences to VBScript, such as macros (called [picture
>   functions](http://blog.fogcreek.com/wasabi-how-do-i-picture-functions/) (don't ask)), lambdas, and simplifications to the
>   declaration system. Don't laugh too much at the former; the motivation
>   was the same as for RJS or Seaside's JavaScript support. All three
>   technologies are dead now, and for good reason, but it was modish at
>   the time.
>
> Later, when .NET came out, and VBScript was end-of-lifed, that left us
>   with the option of rewriting the whole thing...or making a "real"
>   compiler that could compile VBScript to .NET. Wasabi was born. Wasabi
>   was written as a proper compiler that could translate VBScript to C#
>   and (for legacy reasons; see above) JavaScript. Wasabi, unlike
>   Thistle, was a real, full-blown compiler, in a CS sense, so it was
>   feasible to add type inference, lambda expressions, and several other
>   niceties, without spending too much effort. That said, the goal here
>   was to allow transition: new components, with restrictions, could be
>   written in C#. The idea was that, at least hopefully, Wasabi would
>   gradually be deprecated.
>
> So no. It was never meant to be a new language. It was always intended
>   to be a stepping stone, a translator between languages, not a real
>   language in itself. While it gained some additional features, that was
>   to make working in the damn thing palatable--not to be a real language
>   in its own right. Emitting C# and .NET IL are actually about equally
>   easy if you have a real compiler, but Wasabi always emitted C#,
>   specifically so that we could one day ditch the whole thing.

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5281930

See also https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5281322

Answer (score 2):

Its the language Fog Creek made and uses.  Its based on VBScript.